# Pass a dynamic variable in React native super grid under renderItem

Tags: gridview, react-native

I am working on React Native Project, I am using [react-native-super-grid](https://github.com/saleel/react-native-super-grid) this component.

My requirement is to initialize a dynamic variable in the code.

```
<GridView
  itemWidth={130}
  items={[1,2,3,4,5,6]}
  renderItem={item => (<Text>{item}</Text>)}
/>
```

In renderItem section on this location.

```
renderItem={item => (
 ********** Dynamic Variable Here ********** 
 <Text>{item}</Text>
)}
```

How can i pass dynamic variable here so that i can use in next lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
<GridView
  itemWidth={130}
  items={[1,2,3,4,5,6]}
  renderItem={(item) => {this.renderItem(item)}}
/>

renderItem({ item }) {
    this.myVar = 'What you want';
    return (
         <Text>{item}</Text>
    )
}
```

Then you can use this value as follows:

```
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => { alert(this.myVar) }}>  
</TouchableOpacity>
```